# Logcat warning : deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in

Tags: php, android

when i am clicking a button on homepage **'Nearhospitals'** to show nearby hospitals list using location this warning shows on Logcat.

```
deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in <b>/home/content/28/11535728/html/projects/accident/nearhospital.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

There is also other button Nearby Police station which has the same function of this button.when i click on it logcat shows server adress of the police station informations. But when iam clicking **Nearby Hospital button** it only shows warnings.[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BOoC.png)
Does anyone see something where I misplaced something or have made a mistake?

Here is **home.java**

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{

        Button alert;
        RelativeLayout rl1;
        TextView nearhspt;
        TextView nearpolice;
        TextView allhspt;
        TextView allpoli;
        TextView Bld;

        LocationManager locationManager;
        String mprovider;
        // Button service;
        String longitude, latitude;

    //    SharedPreferences shared;
    //    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);
        alert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_alert);
    //        shared = getSharedPreferences("get", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //        editor = shared.edit();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, 15000, 1, this);

                if (location != null)
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TURN ON GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            alert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    String cal = pref.getString("call", "");
                    String sms=pref.getString("msg","");
                    Log.e(cal, "gbggfgffg");
                    Intent inte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    inte.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + cal));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(home.this,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                 //   Uri smsToUri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + sms);

                    // message = message.replace("%s", StoresMessage.m_storeName);
                   //intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);

                    startActivity(inte);

                }
            });}

        public  void  alerthspitl(View view){

            Intent inten = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

            String sms=pref.getString("msg","");

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + sms);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Accident");
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


            public void onBackPressed(){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(home.this);
                alert.setMessage("Do you want to exit?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog al=alert.create();
                al.setTitle("Exit");
                al.show();
                return;
            }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Double longitudes = location.getLongitude();
            longitude =  Double.toString(longitudes);
            Log.e("longitude_value", longitude);

            Double latitudes = location.getLatitude();
            latitude = Double.toString(latitudes);
            Log.e("latiude_value", latitude);

            nearhspt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {







                }
            });


        }
        public void nearhs(View v){
            nearhspt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nearhospitals1);
            SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
            editor.putString("current_longitude", longitude);
            editor.putString("current_latitude", latitude);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,near_hsptl.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    public  void nearpol(View view){
        nearpolice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nearpolicestatn1);
        //Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,near_police.class);
        SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
        editor.putString("current_longitude", longitude);
        editor.putString("current_latitude", latitude);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,near_police.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
        public  void allhsp(View view){
            allhspt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.allhsptl1);
            Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,all_hsptl.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        public  void allpoli(View view){
            allpoli=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.allpolice1);
            Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,all_police.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        public  void Bld(View view){
            allpoli=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.allpolice1);
            Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,blood.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opt, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_settings){
                Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,view_profile.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(id==R.id.up){
                Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,updt_profile.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else  if(id==R.id.pswd){
                Intent intent= new Intent(home.this,updt_pswd.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else  if(id==R.id.logout){
               finishAffinity();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

**Home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9e9e9e"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    >


    <Button
        android:text="Alert police"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#EF5350"

        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_alert"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/download"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_alert"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All Hospitals"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:id="@+id/allhsptl1"
            android:onClick="allhsp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f44336"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Near Hospitals"
            android:onClick="nearhs"
            android:id="@+id/nearhospitals1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f44336"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blood Doners"
            android:onClick="Bld"
            android:id="@+id/Blood_donors"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f44336"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@mipmap/hospital"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All PoliceStation"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:onClick="allpoli"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/allpolice1"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f44336"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Near PoliceStation"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:onClick="nearpol"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/nearpolicestatn1"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#f44336"
            android:layout_weight="5.46" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:text="Alert hospital"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#EF5350"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:onClick="alerthspitl"
        android:id="@+id/button_alert2"

        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.acc_alert">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/emergy_health"
        android:label="Accident Alert"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

<activity android:name=".near_police"/>
        <activity android:name=".near_hsptl"/>
        <activity android:name=".all_police"/>
        <activity android:name=".view_profile"/>
        <activity android:name=".updt_profile"/>
        <activity android:name=".updt_pswd"/>
        <activity android:name=".all_hsptl"/>
        <activity android:name=".home"/>
        <activity android:name=".register"/>
        <activity android:name=".forgetpassword"/>
        <activity android:name=".blood"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The error is in `html/projects/accident/nearhospital.php`. Post that file code.

Comment: error message is very clear, what dont you understand?

Comment: i only have android code @Abhi is the error in php server?

Comment: This error `deg2rad() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in <b>/home/content/28/11535728/html/projects/accident/nearhospital.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />` is most probably in your php server. Your image does not show the error code completely. Post your complete stacktrace.

Comment: Please check first question i was make changes in answer it will work.